# how to use getText function in cucumber with ruby-on-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I am trying to use getText function ,but its giving error.

```
assert_equal "Comment List", find(:xpath,'//div[@id='pageContainer']/div[2]/h2').getText()
```

and error is -

```
C:/Workspace/cucumber-project/features/step_definitions/comment_steps.rb:135: sy ntax error, unexpected ')', expecting kEND ...d='pageContainer']/div[2]/h2').text ^ (SyntaxError)
```

Can anybody help me in that, i just want to compare the text by finding through xpath with the expected text

Comment: Does your line really end with a `.`?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a Cucumber issue, it's a Ruby syntax error. Your quotes are the problem, you need to do either:

```
"//div[@id='pageContainer']/div[2]/h2"
```

or

```
'//div[@id="pageContainer"]/div[2]/h2'
```